# How to browse the asp.net mvc app deployed as guest Executable in service fabric

Tags: azure, web-deployment, guest-executable, azure-service-fabric

I have created Exe of my Asp.net Mvc application now i have deployed the app as a Guest Executable in Service Fabric local cluster. How to browse the pages and how it will get hosted in service fabric?

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: No, i Just deployed the exe in service fabric through VS 2015 but not sure how it will host the application and what steps need to perform.#newtoServiceFabric